# Default locale using Zend Translate with gettext files

Tags: php, internationalization, zend-translate

After hours of battling with `gettext` functions and admitting defeat, I downloaded the Zend Framework for use in my project. It finally worked with the gettext file that I have so far, but now I'm wondering how do I show the default text in the default locale?

Part of my config.php file (it's included in every file at the top):

```
<?php
// ...
define('LANGUAGE', (isset($_GET['lang']) && $_GET['lang'] === 'fr') ? 'fr-CA' : 'en-CA');
define('LOCALE', (isset($_GET['lang']) && $_GET['lang'] === 'fr') ? 'fr_CA' : 'en_CA');
// ...

$translator = new \Zend\I18n\Translator\Translator();
$translator->addTranslationFile('gettext', dirname(__FILE__) . '/locale/' . LOCALE . '.mo', 'messages', LOCALE);
$translator->setLocale(LOCALE);
```

The French translation works fine, but for English it is looking for the `en_CA.mo` file (I'm assuming from the `addTranslationFile()` method) which doesn't exist. How do I make it so that the keys are echoed if the English version is being displayed? It seems redundant to make an en_CA.mo file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are allowing multiple translations for different languages to be translated then you'll need to create at the very least a blank en_CA.mo file. Otherwise, you'll find errors being displayed. Since the en_CA.mo file is blank, the translation keys will be displayed instead of the actual translation itself.

Comment: I was thinking that. Upon implementation though, the Translator class tried to parse the empty file: `Uncaught exception 'Zend\I18n\Exception\InvalidArgumentException' with message '/home/user/public_html/project/includes/locale/en_CA.mo is not a valid gettext file' in /home/user/public_html/project/libraries/Zend/I18n/Translator/Loader/Gettext.php:80`

Comment: The translation file has to have at least the header information. I recommend to try using PoEdit and create the file there. You could even try adding at least 1 translation key to be translated this way you know for certain that file has the required header information. Instead of just trying to create a blank and empty file.

Comment: It worked, guess I just needed a blank translation file. Thanks.